# Using for loop in Express Router (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to use for loop like so. But I don't get 'console.log(i)' in my terminal while I do get 'console.log(req.body)' correctly. Please help.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = new express.Router();

router.post("/basic", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.send(req.body);
    console.log(req.body)

    for (let i=0; i < 5, i++; ) {
      console.log(i);
    }

  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: try to add value on your i
`for (let i = 0; i < 5, i++; )`

Answer (score 2):

As you declare the variable `let i`; it has the value `undefined`; So there are 2 types of `undefined` in javascript:

> You may get `undefined` when a variable was not defined (does not exist), and second the variable exists but the value is `undefined` the variable exists.

next in the `for`the operation follows `i < 5 (undefined < 5)` which is `false` and it exits the for loop so this is why you are not getting the `console.log` output.

The simplest solution as suggested by @Rap Sherlock `let i = 0;`

**After Edit:**

There is an other typo in the code:

```
for (let i=0; i < 5, i++; ) { // should be

// need to use ; instead of ,
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. Actually, I have 'let i = 0' in my code.

Comment: Edited the response

Answer (score 0):

"i" is undefined because you did not initlize its value.

Try

```js
for(let i = 0; i< 5; i++){
   //your code
}
```

Notice the  **let i = 0;**

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. Actually, I have 'let i = 0' in my code.